# wordpress php problem, getting custom field image or default image

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, image, if-statement

Hi all this is wordpress php question
I am trying to get thumbnail from custom field image. Please help me with the code thank you so much.

```
<?php
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail', true)) {
echo "<img src='echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail', true)' width='100px' />";
}else{
echo "<img src='http://site.com/default.jpg' width='50px' />";
}   
?>
```

Above code results default pic where custom field image is not added but is giving out img code shown below as output for custom filled image.

```
<img src='echo get_post_meta(86, ''thumbnail'', true)' width='100px' />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely is that you have an `echo` statement inside another `echo` statement.

```
<?php
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail', true)) {
echo "<img src='" . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail', true) . "' width='100px' />";
}else{
echo "<img src='http://site.com/default.jpg' width='50px' />";
}   
?>
```

Comment: Ya works thanks a lot. I knew it was problem with quotes in echo statement, just didn't know how to fix it :) Thanks again